# Rails routes redirect with symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, routes

I have built a re-design of an old site in rails. All the URL's of the new rails site are different from the existing one. Some of these links are still indexed in google and on other peoples websites.

In the routes I am doing:

```
get "/oldurl", :to => redirect("/newurl")
```

That works fine, however most of the urls have symbols like "?" and "=" and doing:

```
get "/?=oldurl", :to => redirect("/about")
```

won't work so I was wondering how I route old urls with ?= symbols to the new urls.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: better you could do redirect in web server level like apache or nginx?

Comment: I'd agree - this is much better solved with nginx/apache: cleaner and much faster.

Answer (score 0):

try  this

```
match "/",  :to => redirect do |params, request| 
  '/about' if request.params.has_key?(:oldurl) 
end
```